# How to fit HTML table images to window height?

Tags: html, css, html-table, image-resizing

First of all, my idea is to create my site with portfolio images auto-fit to browser window height. I'm not an expert in html code, but I think I'm very close to what I want to looks like.

HERE is my problem: http://www.stelianpopa.ro/photo-outdoor.html

**CSS:**

```
table{
height: 100% !important;
border-collapse:collapse;
border-spacing:1px;
position: absolute;
z-index: -100;
}

table td{
width: 100% !important;
position: relative;
vertical-align: middle;
}

table td img {
height: 100% !important;
margin-right: 5px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td><img src="http://www.stelianpopa.ro/uploads/series/ld0.jpg"></td>
<td><img src="http://www.stelianpopa.ro/uploads/series/ld0.jpg"></td>
<td><img src="http://www.stelianpopa.ro/uploads/series/ld0.jpg"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Right now the code seems to work only **IF YOU ENTER FIRST TIME** in the gallery, if you refreh or enter again the code crash and images are height fit but **overlapping**.

PLEASE HELP ME to corect the code and the images not the overlapping when you refresh the page.
PS: The codes are tested in Chrome, In other browsers doesn't work at all, they don't resize... why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some recommendations. Lose the use of tables.

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://www.stelianpopa.ro/uploads/series/ld0.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.stelianpopa.ro/uploads/series/ld0.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.stelianpopa.ro/uploads/series/ld0.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

Then in your CSS the important factor for 100% height is every parent must also utilize 100%, this includes html and body.

```
html,body {
    height: 100%;
}
ul {
    white-space: nowrap; /* stops li elements from wrapping to next line */
    height: 100%;
}
li {
    list-style: none; /* just to remove dotted list */
    height: 100%;
    display: inline; /* makes list elements horizontal */
}
img {
    height:100%;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wboco/VRYWg/1/

*** Why was this marked correctly then removed?

Remove:

```
<div class="single-img">    
<div id="gallery">
```

from wrapping the unordered list on your site. Then add the CSS to ul li and img that I provided earlier. It's 100% functional.

Comment: It's working perfectly in Chrome, you're amazing. Thx a lot.
It's 100% functional EVEN NOW, but only in chrome. I can't remove

    <div id="gallery">

because it will crash another code in http://www.stelianpopa.ro/photo-editorial.html.

Comment: The code stop working from few days ago. I don't know why because I didn't change NOTHING. Is it possible to be some Chrome updates issues?

Answer (score 0):

To fit an element entire height of the page, you need to set height of all prior elements.

So, try this CSS:

```
html, body { height: 95% }
```

And set the height of other elements containing your table, if there.

Answer (score 0):

First set your `<div class="space"></div>` height to 0px.
Change your img tag to div and set background image.

```
<div class="single-img">    
   <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"style='width:100%!important;height:100%!important;'>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td style='width:100%!important;height:100%!important;'> 
           <div style='width:100%!important;height:100%!important; background-image:url(image1);' ></div>
           </td>           
          </tr>
           <!-- another images  ...  -->
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```